# Eclipse + Cygwin = Program "make" is not found in PATH

Tags: eclipse, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I have `cygwin` installed and can normally compile project from command line with `make`.

Now how to compile the same project with eclipse?

It says

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project leptonica-1.69 ****

****  WARNING: The "Default" Configuration may not build  ****
****  because it uses the "cdt.managedbuild.toolchain.gnu.cygwin.base"  ****
****  tool-chain that is unsupported on this system.  ****

****  Attempting to build...  **** 

make all 

Cannot run program "make": Launching failed
Error: Program "make" is not found in PATH
```

if I try to compile.

I found no place to setup CDT with some location of `cygwin`. Of course, I don't want to add `cygwin` paths to global windows path.

Is it possible to set it only for eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the path (and other variables) in `Eclipse Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment`, i.e. add variable `PATH` with a value of `${PATH};C:\cygwin\bin`.

(edit: removed second paragraph with stuff I had misinterpreted)